# Function taking two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, zclip

So I have the following link:

```
<div class="upload-copy" id="<?php echo $row['RandomName'] . '-html'; ?>" onclick="javascript:getID(this)">Copy To Clipboard</div>
```

That when clicked it should copy an input using the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getID(theLink){

        var clickid = '#' + theLink.id;
        var inputid = clickid + '-input';

        $(clickid).zclip({
            path:'js/vendor/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:function(){return $(inputid).val();},
            afterCopy:function(){
            $(clickid).html('Copied');
        }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Now this works but only when you click the link twice. How can I make it so it fires on the first click?

Comment: I only have to click once in IE9 and FF18, http://jsfiddle.net/armnP/ My guess is you have some odd markup around or over the DIV that is eating your first click event (possibly as a focus or because you have some .preventDefault() or .stopPropegation() calls somewhere.

Comment: It's not the click function that's causing the issue. It's the zclip script firing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the jQuery click function.

Just use the class you have for the click then get the ID attribute and do your other bits and pieces.

```
$(".upload-copy").click(function() {

  var linkid = $(this).attr("id");

  // your other code

});
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue and I think it is to do with the zclip script. Because it relies on flash for the copy, it has to make the element I'm clicking in to flash so what is happening is that when I click the element once, it is converted to flash and then when I click it again, because its now flash it will copy. Just trying to see if there is a way to enable flash on the element without the first click needed.